# How to get list of all scopes of ActiveRecord (rails 3.1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

How can I get a list of all scopes in an ActiveRecord model using Rails 3.1?

According the documentation for 3.0.9 there is supposed to be a method called "scopes" http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scopes, but that method doesn't seem to exist.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You can use `Model.send(:valid_scope_name?, scope_name)` to test if the scope exists in that class. Scopes did make sense in Rails 2.x but no longer in 3.x, where you have relation objects.

So instead:

```
 scope :red_ones, where(color: 'red')
```

You would have:

```
 def self.red_ones
   where(color: 'red')
 end
```

Comment: I didn't want to use valid_scope_name? since it is a protected method and logs a strange warning message:logger.warn "Creating scope :#{name}. "                        "Overwriting existing method #{self.name}.#{name}."

I want to use scopes rather than methods (as you suggested) because it makes my code nicer and I want to be able to test if it is a scope or not as the documentation specifies should be possible.

Comment: I ran into this issue testing the presence of a scope. I changed my assertion from 'assert klass.scopes.include?(name)' to 'assert klass.name'. This doesn't answer the above question but it did help me. Hopefully this helps someone else.

Comment: opps. the last code should have been 'assert klass.try(name)' where 'name' is the name of the scope.

Comment: `valid_scope_name?` just calls the method `respond_to?` behind the scenes. Thats bad, because this means that dangerous methods also pass as scopes, e.g. `destroy_all`!

Comment: sorry, but i dont think this answers the question...
i came here for same reason as OP, i want to see sth like this (please see answer for better readability....